# How to make this nicer in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I this piece of code I would like to know instead of having convert() separate can I have anonymous in map {}

```
fun <A, B> LiveData<A>.map(function: (A) -> B): LiveData<B> = Transformations.map(this, function)

fun loadSettings() {
    configLiveData.map { configFile ->
      return@map convert(configFile)
    }
  }

  fun convert(configFile: Response<ConfigFile>): MutableLiveData<Settings> {
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<Setting>()
    when (configFile) {
      is Response.Success<ConfigFile> -> {
        mutableData.postValue(configFile.data.config?.settings)
      }
      is Response.Failure -> {
        errorMessageMutableData.postValue(it.message)
      }
    }
    return mutableData
}
```

final result I have

```
fun loadTheme(): LiveData<Response<Theme?>> {
    return configLiveData.map { configFile ->

      when (configFile) {
        is Response.Success<ConfigFile> -> {
          Response.Success(configFile.data.config?.theme)
        }
        is Response.Failure -> {
          Response.Failure(configFile.message)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can I have anonymous in map {}

Yes, of course. You already do: `{ configFile -> return@map convert(configFile) }` is a lambda (which could equally be written `{ configFile -> convert(configFile) }` or `{ convert(it) }`, or even `::convert`). If you don't want to make `convert` a separate function, just inline it into the lambda:

```
configLiveData.map { configFile ->
    val mutableData = MutableLiveData<Setting>()
    when (configFile) {
        is Response.Success<ConfigFile> -> {
            mutableData.postValue(configFile.data.config?.settings)
        }
        is Response.Failure -> {
            errorMessageMutableData.postValue(it.message)
        }
    }
    mutableData // no need for return@map
}
```

But the problem is that if that's your real code, it probably doesn't actually do what you want, because

1. you create a `LiveData<MutableLiveData<Settings>>` (did you want [`switchMap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/Transformations.html#switchMap(android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CX%3E,%20android.arch.core.util.Function%3CX,%20android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData%3CY%3E%3E)) instead of `map`?);
2. you then throw it away;
3. if you get a `Response.Success`, it's effectively ignored (because you just `post` data from it into an unobserved `LiveData`).

Comment: I have configLiveData and I want to fetch settings and observe settingsData(mutableData) in fragment ,
 should I use switchMap?

Comment: I would just create `mutableData` outside (like you presumably do with `errorMessageMutableData`) and `post` to it in an observer on `configLiveData`. `switchMap` can be used too.

Comment: Thanks will do it. and concerning  switchMap in cases when I need to do another request during transformation I do switchMap but in this simple cases map. do you agree?

Comment: @ArturA Just looking at the types should tell you. Again: 1. if you don't use the result it should likely be just `addObserver`. Both `map` and `switchMap` return results which should be used. 2. Here `map` gives you `LiveData<MutableLiveData<Settings>>`. Is that what you want?

Comment: ``` fun loadTheme(): LiveData<Response<Theme?>> {
    return configLiveData.map { configFile ->

      when (configFile) {
        is Response.Success<ConfigFile> -> {
          Response.Success(configFile.data.config?.theme)
        }
        is Response.Failure -> {
          Response.Failure(configFile.message)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```
I see thanks Iearnt something new .

Comment: @Alexsey Romanov 
I have edited my question and you can see how it looks like
but what I  am thinking is there any way to avoid returning Result.Failure case?
and when you mentioned addObserve but in that case I need to have lifecycleOwner yes? but I am in ViewModel